# custom network protocol for linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to implement a custom UDP protocol for Linux kernel for college project. I also need to implement a user land program that communicates using the protocol. I am looking for a detailed guide on it including sample code, but could not find it anywhere. Most of the books are deal with theory but I want something more practical - which files to change and which functions to implement specifically for Linux kernel.

Comment: Why do you need to do anything in the kernel?

Comment: by "custom udp" you mean that the socket.h functions that implement UDP won't work for you?

Comment: its for pure learning purposes.

Comment: I want the protocol to have custom fields like number of "A"'s in the data. TCP is fairly complex to start with.

Comment: @user361697: If all you want to do is implement a protocol on top of UDP, you should be able to do everything you need using [sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) in user-space.

Comment: Just to say that the question is valid and good. It is a pity that finding answer to it is so hard. Most people point out that you should not do anything complex in the kernel. While true, they completely miss the point that we need to learn what the kernel is capable of, and also that sometimes the definition of a task is beyond our control.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

(Programming Linux sockets, Part 2: Using UDP)

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-sock2/

Comment: Broken link, please fix.

Answer (score 0):

In the Linux kernel, the UDP implementation for IPV4 is in:

linux-a.b.c/net/ipv4/udp.c

That's a good starting point. Check the functions this UDP implementation exports to other network layer protocols, so you can create your own version of this protocol, export your own functions to other network layer protocols and call then from there.

For example, when the network layer protocol (IP) finishes the processing of an incoming packet, it calls `udp_rcv()` to deliver packet to UDP when the upper layer protocol is UDP (value 17, according to IANA, in the protocol field of IPV4's header).

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Edition by O'Reilly Chapter 17](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch17.html).

Additionally, in the Linux source tree, a couple of drivers to start looking at include:

> drivers/net/loopback.c
>
> drivers/net/plip/plip.c